# Add class to parent div using ajax

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I want to add class to the parent div but I am using ajax so I don't know to target the correct parent. Here is my code:

```
function mark_watched(show, season, episode, path){
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: path,
            type: "POST",
            data: "show=" + show + "&season=" + season + "&episode=" + episode,
            success: function (result){
                if(result=="marked"){
                    $(".mark_watched").parent(".calendar_episode").addClass("ep_watched");
                }
                else if (result=="unmarked") {
                    $(".mark_watched").parent(".calendar_episode").removeClass("ep_watched");
                }
            },
        });
        return false;
    });                                     
}
```

I created a jsfiddle example for what I want to achieve. Check it out here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Losr8htj/)

The thing is, in the jsfiddle example I can use the keyword `this` to target the correct checkbox parent, however in the ajax code from above, it is targeting all parent divs having the class `calendar_episode`.

How can I target the correct one?

Comment: yes..you are right ..in jsfiddle its target that element only.but your ajax code target will all the element contain the same class name  of the `mark_watched`

Comment: So how do I target the correct one?

Comment: How are you calling the mark_watched function?

Comment: How is mark_watched being called. If it is being called with onchange you should have access to the event and then the event.target.

Comment: `$(".mark_watched").eq(0)` its target the first element with same classname.But you need addclass with respected element .you need to pass the element with function .And declare with some other variable before ajax call.its just like event.target

Comment: pass to ajax method `context: this,` then inside `success` callback use `$(this).parent(".calendar_episode").addClass("ep_watched");`. And as a side note, this is useless to use `$(function() {...});` wrapper here (i guess)

Comment: Yes, it is called with onmouseup. @A.Wolff, I tried what you said but it's not working.

Comment: It works but i don't know which exact code you are using. It should be: `$.ajax({context: this, ..., ` then in success use: `$(this).parent(".calendar_episode").addClass("ep_watched");` and the same for removeClass

Comment: I edited it just like this and it is not working.

Comment: I see that it's probably because the way you bind event. You should bind event using jq method, not inline script. It means don't use `onmouseup` attribute but use e.g: `$(function(){$(".mark_watched").on('mouseup', mark_watched);});` and remove `$(function(){...});` wrapper inside `mark_watched` function

Comment: I don't understand. How am I going to parse the parameters then?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try saving $(this) in a variable to use later. Clicking the button would toggle the ep_watched class on the item you selected last.

That said if A. Wolff's comment works, that might be more elegant.

**JS-Fiddle**

[JS-Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Losr8htj/2/)

**html**

```
<div class="calendar_episode">
<input type="checkbox" class="mark_watched"> 
</div>
<div class="calendar_episode">
<input type="checkbox" class="mark_watched"> 
</div>
<div class="calendar_episode">
<input type="checkbox" class="mark_watched"> 
</div>
<button>Run function</button>
```

**css**

```
.ep_watched {
    opacity: 0.6;
    background: rgb(235, 235, 235);
}
```

**JS / jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    let selectedInput = null;
    $(".mark_watched").on("change", function() {
      selectedInput= $(this);    
    });
    $("button").click(function(){
            addEpWatched(); 
    });
function addEpWatched(){
 selectedInput.parent(".calendar_episode").toggleClass("ep_watched");
 }
});
```